# Relative abundance of the isotopes of iridium

Tags: atoms

There are two stable isotopes of iridium, $\ce{^191Ir}$ and $\ce{^193Ir}$. If you randomly pick an iridium atom from a large collection of iridium atoms, which isotope are you more likely to select?

Comment: It depends on which isotope is more abundant. There should be tabulated values of these; a quick internet search will throw them up.

Comment: even in the exams right ?

Comment: Clearly not, but you'd expect such information to be given to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An urn contains nothing but

- 63 white balls and
- 37 black balls.

You grab into the urn, pick one item, look at it and put it back.

What is the probability that you drew:

- a ball
- a white ball
- a black ball
- a red ball?

Comment: 1) 100% 2)63% 3)37% 4)0%

Comment: @shaima Exactly :) Amazingly, 63% and 37% are roughly the abundancies of the two natural iridium isotopes: $\ce{^{193}Ir}$ and $\ce{^{191}Ir}$